# Asp.Net Core : Generating Auth Token for Apple Device Check throws System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException

Tags: ios, security, jwt, asp.net-core-webapi

We're implementing Apple's Device Check within our Asp.net core Web api. The functionality works absolutely fine on our dev environment but crashes on production. We use [jose-jwt](https://github.com/dvsekhvalnov/jose-jwt) for generating the JWT token and RestSharp for the api calls. Since there is a lot of code, I've created a gist for this [here](https://gist.github.com/mshenoy83/139da4289da37b05c76133a37a77be6c)

This works absolutely fine on our development server. And on the production server we get this error

Production : Windows 2012 R2

Development : Windows 2016 server

> System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: The requested operation is not supported. at System.Security.Cryptography.NCryptNative.ImportKey(SafeNCryptProviderHandle provider, Byte[] keyBlob, String format) at System.Security.Cryptography.CngKey.Import(Byte[] keyBlob, CngKeyBlobFormat format, CngProvider provider) at Security.Cryptography.EccKey.New(Byte[] x, Byte[] y, Byte[] d, CngKeyUsages usage) at AppleDeviceCheck.GetPrivateKey() in AppleDeviceCheck.cs:line 53 at CustomerAppCoreAPI.Utilities.AppleDeviceCheck.GetProviderToken() in 
>   AppleDeviceCheck.cs:line 65 at AppleDeviceCheck.AddRequestHeaders(String resource) in AppleDeviceCheck.cs:line 106 at AppleDeviceCheck.ValidateDeviceToken(DeviceCheckRequestModel request) in AppleDeviceCheck.cs:line 83

Not sure why this error pops up. Any help would be appreciated.